# How to use ng-bind-html?

Tags: angularjs

Any ideas why this bind isn't working?

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML = "<a href='#'>a link</a>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the HTML binding to work, your module needs to have `ngSanitize` injected as well as the file `angular-sanitize(.min).js` included.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ngSanitize']);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.myHTML = "<a href='#'>a link</a>";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.6/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <p ng-bind-html="myHTML"></p>
</div>
```

Or you can use [String Contextual Escaping](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce#) (which will probably be **the** way to do it in future versions of Angular).

Comment: Thanks!  I went with $sce.  More concise.